# ScrollToRow does not work when said row is near the bottom of the table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll, indexpath

I have a cell class which implements a textfield delegate. In this delegate I am calling a function to tell the tableview to scroll to a specific row based off an indexPath. This works in most cases but not when the row is at the bottom of the table view. The cell class has a table property which is passed in, in my main controllers cellForRow method. Code below:

```
extension IR_TextCell: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        util_textField.addHightlightedBorder(textField)
        if let index = table?.indexPath(for: self)
        {
            scrollDelegate?.scrollToMe(at: index)
        }
    }
}

func scrollToMe(at index: IndexPath) {
    self.tableV.scrollToRow(at: index, at: .middle, animated: false)
}
```

I have tried wrapping DispatchQueue.main.async around this and adding a deadline but it didn't make a difference.

Do I need to change my tableview's bottom constraint maybe?

Comment: I think is bad approach to keep a reference of the table inside of cell, you must handle this with a delegate or closure

Comment: @ReinierMelian is there a way to grab the indexPath of the cell within the cell class without having a tableview property?

Comment: Yes, you can add an indexpath property in your cell and in a delegate method pass this indexpath to your viewController and your viewController must make the scroll in the table

Comment: @ReinierMelian of course! thanks :) I swapped out the tableview ref for an IndexPath ref. I still have the exact same issue, however.. does not work for the bottom row

Comment: Your issue with the bottom row, seems to be your .middle param in the scrollToRow method, you can add a UIEdgeInset for that case and must work properly

Comment: @ReinierMelian Where in my scrollToMe func would I add UIEdgeInset? I'm not following exactly. I tried .bottom also.

Comment: I will try to post an answer after some test, if works i will post an answer about this

Answer (score 0):

My situation is a little different than yours but I had a same issue scrolling to cells that are near the bottom. It might now work for your exact situation but I hope this helps someone who comes across this posting. I suspected that it might be a timing issue so I ended up doing it like below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.last?.row {

        let scrollIndex = 0//set to your predetermined scrolled to index
        let cellRect = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
        let completelyVisible = tableView.bounds.contains(cellRect)

        if scrollIndex >= indexPath.row && !completelyVisible {
            let maxIndex = 10//number of elements in the array - 1
            //in case you want a delay
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0)  {
                self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: scrollIndex > maxIndex ? maxIndex : scrollIndex, section: 0), at: .middle, animated: false)
            }
        }

    }
}
```